# PHPUnit report marks untested methods as tested

Tags: unit-testing, report, phpunit, zend-framework2

I wrote two simple model classes in my Zend Framework 2 application: `Catalog\Model\City` `Catalog\Model\CityTyble`. For none of these any unit tests have been written yet. But when I create a report (`user@machine:/path/to/project/module/Catalog/test# phpunit --coverage-html ./report`), one of the classes is shown as tested:

[image]

...and the methods:

[image]

There are no test method for this class, not even the a class exists.

What is here wrong? Why is this untested classe / are these untested methods shown as tested?

Answer (score 2):

This report does not exactly mean that the code is being tested. The report only says that those lines are being executed. So if you have tests that execute certain lines, you assume that they are being tested. To get this information, PHPUnit uses [PHP_CodeCoverage](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.8/en/code-coverage-analysis.html)

Do you have any code that could be being executed by PHPUnit? As said in the report, you have code somewhere that PHPUnit is executing, that is creating an instance of *CityTable* and calling the method *fetchAll()*

If you are using [a configuration file](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.8/en/appendixes.configuration.html), check if you are telling PHPUnit to execute the right files.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! No, there is no model code, that is executed in the unit tests _directly_. There are only one test class (`CatalogControllerTest`), that contains three methods for three controller actions (one of these methods executes one model action). But the strangest thing is: I've just commented all tests (all three controller test methods) out, created a new report, then removed the comments, created the report again -- and now only the `CatalogController.php` is displayed... So, now it's working as expected. I cannot reproduce the strange behavior, I described above.